# How to create TTS queue?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

How can I use DispatchGroup or DispatchQueue? I want to create TTS sequence. I have Tableview  with objects.  Buf if I tap before startalking finished, it is not talking other objects. I want to tap object even talking and add this object name talking to queue.

I tried but it is not working.

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
group.enter()
let stringText = String(format: NSLocalizedString("Searching %@", comment: ""), object)
startTalking(string: stringText) { (isFinished) in
    group.leave()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `OperationQueue`. It is easier to manage and automatically supports cancelling.

So approach can be as follows

```
// somewhere in init()
let talkingQueue = OperationQueue()
talkingQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1 // this makes it serial

// in onTap handler
let stringText = String(format: NSLocalizedString("Searching %@", comment: ""), object)
self.talkingQueue.addOperation {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    startTalking(string: stringText) { (isFinished) in
        group.leave()
    }
}

// in case u need to cancel
self.talkingQueue.cancelAllOperations()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried but if I tap more than once, it crashes at group.leave() line. Should I move group.enter above addOperation?

Comment: is startTalking async function?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use DispatchGroup or DispatchQueue?

To understand how the `Dispatch_group` works, try the code snippet hereafter:

```
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    func hello(str: String, completionHandler: () -> Void) {
        print(str)
        completionHandler()
    }

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    hello(str: "hello 1", completionHandler: { dispatchGroup.leave() })

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    hello(str: "hello 2", completionHandler: { dispatchGroup.leave() })

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) { print("Everything works perfectly ") }
```

... and get the following result:
[image]

⚠️ You must balance out the number of `dispatch_group_enter` calls with the number of `dispatch_group_leave` calls otherwise you may encounter weird issues.